# Jest snapshots are failing when I update third party library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I'm using jest snapshots for testing my react application and everytime I update our component library (a package with generic react components of the compañy) all test fail because the classname used by the package includes its version. For example, a typical classname looks like `lesson-card__1-7-0`, 1-7-0 being the version of the componnt library.
So everytime a snapshots is generated it includes the library version, and when you update it to, lets say, 1-7-1, every test filas.

The library includes the version in the classnames to avoid collisions in case microservices are using different versions of the library.

So, the option I thought is to customize the `toMatchSnapshot()` method to ignore the version when comparing. Maybe removing the version so the snapshots are saved without that. The problem is it doesnt seem posible to customize the function.

Does anyone knows how can I do that? Or can think of any other solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: My suggestion would be: _don't_ use snapshots. As you're finding out, they're just _change detection_ not actual testing, they don't tell you whether or not the code still _works_ in any meaningful way.

Comment: Yeah, I would love to do that, but there are already more than 2000 test, and more than 100 people working on the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up redefining de global expect jest function:

```
const originalExpect = expect

// Match patterns of the form __3-4-5__ (including the underscores)
const toMatch = /__\d+-\d+-\d+__/g

// Each node of the tree has only 3 properties: a type, props and children.
// Inside the props it is the className, we remove substrings of the className
// using the match form. If the node has children, then we recursively walk through them.
function removeCLVersion(obj) {
    if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') return obj
    if ('props' in obj && 'className' in obj.props) obj.props.className = obj.props.className.replace(toMatch, '__')
    if ('children' in obj && obj.children) obj.children = obj.children.map(element => removeCLVersion(element))
    return obj
}

// Javascript functions cant be changed, so we are replacing it with a custom one that
// removes the CL version of the received object in the toMatchSnapshot method
global.expect = received => {
    const resultObject = originalExpect(received)
    resultObject.toMatchSnapshot = () => originalExpect(removeCLVersion(received)).toMatchSnapshot()
    return resultObject
}
// And then we add the methods of the original function to our new expect function
Object.assign(expect, {...originalExpect})
```

I did this in the jest setupFilesAfterEnv. It can be used to rewrite any method of the expect result object.